# The first item of a Sales Order does not load correctly - Netsuite ClientScript Suitescript

Tags: netsuite

First of all, if someone can help me understand why this happens, I would appreciate it. It is my first development and in Netsuite.

I have a script that, being activated from a button, reads the information of an inventory transfer and converts it into a sales order. Everything has turned out fine except for:

When the sales order is created, the item added on the first line is not loaded properly, and when given fullfilment, the system excludes that item. I show you:

[Inventory Transfer Item Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiHM8.png)

[Sales Order Item Lines (Created by script)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PnNW.png)

[Fulfillment Item Lines (Only 6 items)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdDLA.png)

I share the part of the code that I have to fill the lines of articles.

```
var itSearch = search.create({
           type: "inventorytransfer",
           filters:
           [
              ["type","anyof","InvTrnfr"], 
              "AND", 
              ["internalid","anyof",it.id], 
              "AND", 
              ["mainline","is","F"], 
              "AND", 
              ["location","anyof",it.getValue('transferlocation')]
           ],
           columns:
           [
              search.createColumn({name: "item", label: "Item"}),
              search.createColumn({name: "quantity", label: "Quantity"}),
              search.createColumn({
                 name: "formulanumeric",
                 formula: "0",
                 label: "Rate"
              }),
              search.createColumn({name: "unit", label: "Units"}),
              search.createColumn({name: "location", label: "Location"}),
              search.createColumn({
                 name: "class",
                 formula: it.getValue('class'),
                 label: "Class"
              }),
              search.createColumn({name: "custcol_kx_revenue_start_date", label: "Kx Revenue Start Date"}),
              search.createColumn({name: "custcol_kx_revenue_end_date", label: "Kx Revenue End Date"}),
              search.createColumn({name: "custcol_celigo_sfio_order_id", label: "Salesforce Order Line Id (IO)"}),
              search.createColumn({name: "custcol_celigo_sfio_sf_id", label: "Salesforce Opportunity Line Id (IO)"}),
              search.createColumn({name: "custcol1", label: "Purchase order"})
           ]
        });
         
         var sResult = itSearch.run();
         var resultRange = sResult.getRange({
           start: 0,
           end: 100
         });
         var sLines = resultRange.length;
     

for (var i=0 ; i<sLines ; i++){
              so.selectNewLine({sublistId:'item'});
              so.setCurrentSublistValue({
                      sublistId:'item',
                      fieldId:'item',
                      value:resultRange[i].getValue({name: 'item'}),
                      ignoreFieldChange: true,
                      forceSyncSourcing: true
              });
              so.setCurrentSublistValue({
                      sublistId:'item',
                      fieldId:'quantity',
                      value:resultRange[i].getValue({name: 'quantity'}),
                      ignoreFieldChange: true,
                      forceSyncSourcing: true
              });
              so.setCurrentSublistValue({
                      sublistId:'item',
                      fieldId:'rate',
                      value:'0',
                      ignoreFieldChange: true,
                      forceSyncSourcing: true
              });
              so.setCurrentSublistValue({
                      sublistId:'item',
                      fieldId:'amount',
                      value:'0',
                      ignoreFieldChange: true,
                      forceSyncSourcing: true
              });
              so.setCurrentSublistValue({
                      sublistId:'item',
                      fieldId:'price',
                      value:null,
                      ignoreFieldChange: true,
                      forceSyncSourcing: true
              });
              so.setCurrentSublistValue({
                      sublistId:'item',
                      fieldId:'class',
                      value:resultRange[i].getValue({name: 'class'}),
                      ignoreFieldChange: true,
                      forceSyncSourcing: true
              });
              so.setCurrentSublistValue({
                      sublistId:'item',
                      fieldId:'location',
                      value:resultRange[i].getValue({name: 'location'}),
                      ignoreFieldChange: true,
                      forceSyncSourcing: true
              });
              so.setCurrentSublistValue({
                      sublistId:'item',
                      fieldId:'units',
                      value:resultRange[i].getValue({name: 'units'}),
                      ignoreFieldChange: true,
                      forceSyncSourcing: true
              });
              so.setCurrentSublistValue({
                      sublistId:'item',
                      fieldId:'custcol_kx_revenue_start_date',
                      value:resultRange[i].getValue({name: 'custcol_kx_revenue_start_date'}),
                      ignoreFieldChange: true,
                      forceSyncSourcing: true
              });
              so.setCurrentSublistValue({
                      sublistId:'item',
                      fieldId:'custcol_kx_revenue_end_date',
                      value:resultRange[i].getValue({name: 'custcol_kx_revenue_end_date'}),
                      ignoreFieldChange: true,
                      forceSyncSourcing: true
              });
              so.setCurrentSublistValue({
                      sublistId:'item',
                      fieldId:'custcol_celigo_sfio_order_id',
                      value:resultRange[i].getValue({name: 'custcol_celigo_sfio_order_id'}),
                      ignoreFieldChange: true,
                      forceSyncSourcing: true
              });
              so.setCurrentSublistValue({
                      sublistId:'item',
                      fieldId:'custcol_celigo_sfio_sf_id',
                      value:resultRange[i].getValue({name: 'custcol_celigo_sfio_sf_id'}),
                      ignoreFieldChange: true,
                      forceSyncSourcing: true
              });
              so.setCurrentSublistValue({
                      sublistId:'item',
                      fieldId:'custcol1',
                      value:resultRange[i].getValue({name: 'custcol1'}),
                      ignoreFieldChange: true,
                      forceSyncSourcing: true
              });
              so.setCurrentSublistValue({
                      sublistId:'item',
                      fieldId:'line.cseg_paactivitycode',
                      value:resultRange[i].getValue({name: 'line.cseg_paactivitycode'}),
                      ignoreFieldChange: true,
                      forceSyncSourcing: true
              });

              so.commitLine({sublistId:'item'});
   //             so.selectNewLine({sublistId:'item'});
           }
                
          /*SAVE*/
          var idso = so.save({ignoreMandatoryFields: true});
```

Comment: What is the item type of the first item? I suppose, it's a non-inventory item? Is the checkbox 'can be fulfilled' unchecked?

Comment: yes, that is not the problem. Thank you

Comment: If the checkbox ‘can be fulfilled’ is unchecked, then that is your problem..